# If statement to determine what class is added on mouse click

Tags: javascript

Im using javascript *if* statement to check if an element has the class *shrink* and if it has it, run a function and if its not run over function here is my javascript

```
if (document.getElementById('green-player').className = 'shrink';)) 
{ 
    addclassgreen();
}
```

Comment: What's your question/problem/cup of tea that belongs to this code?

Comment: Please read any basic JavaScript manual first. Especially the section about `if` statements.

Comment: it doesnt work lol i want this to be triggered on mouse down so if mouse down is on #green-player and it has a class of shrink change it to enlarge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (document.getElementById('green-player').className == 'shrink') {              
    addclassgreen();
}
```

Comment: cheers bro ill tick this when the 8 mins are up!!